# How to extract in Splunk at indexed time json field with same child-key from different father-key using regex?

Tags: json, regex, splunk

We have to model a regex in order to extract in Splunk (at index time) some fileds from our event. These fields will be used in search using the `tstats` command. The regex will be used in a configuration file in Splunk settings (`transformation.conf`).

The main aspect of the fields we want extract at index time is that they have the same json key but a different father json-key.

Is it possible modelling this extraction using regex?

This is an example of Splunk event having the structure described before (json by the way):

```
{
   "info":{
      "eventSource":"",
      "sourceType":"I/O",
      "status":{
         "code":"",
         "msg":"",
         "msgError":""
      },
      "transactionId":null,
      "traceId":null,
      "timestampStart":"2019-05-16T21:30:55.174Z",
      "timestampEnd":"2019-05-16T21:30:55.174Z",
      "companyIDCode":"",
      "channelIDCode":"",
      "branchCode":"",
      "searchFields":{
         "key_3":"value",
         "key_2":"value",
         "key_1":"value"
      },
      "annotation":{},
      "caller":{
         "id":"",
         "version":"",
         "acronym":""
      },
      "called":{
         "id":"",
         "version":"",
         "acronym":""
      },
         "storage":{
            "id":"",
            "start":"",
            "end":""
         }
      }
   },
   "headers":[],
   "payLoad":{
      "input":{
         "encoding":"1024",
         "ccsid":"1024",
         "data":"dati_in"
      },
      "output":{
         "encoding":"1024",
         "ccsid":"1024",
         "data":"dati_out"
      }
   }
}
```

The attended result is something like that:

- calledid -> aaa
- callerversion -> 1
- callerid -> bbb

We tried something like that

```
[calledid]
REGEX = (?<=called).*"id":"(?P<calledid>.*?)(?=")
FORMAT = calledid::"$1"
WRITE_META = true
```

but it  dowsn't work cause it matches until the last id he finds. Such as:

```
":{"id":"","version":"","acronym":""},"storage":{"id":"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `.*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't work

Comment: [It does](https://regex101.com/r/b4W5Y1/1)

Comment: In Splunk, you need to extract the fields at ingest time for it to work with `tstats`. Splunk can be configured to do so. Use INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = JSON in props.conf.

Comment: Can this question *please* stop being marked as a duplicate

Comment: @SimonDuff do you mean under the source type stanza in pros.conf?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: @SimonDuff yes it's working, we have only to deal about the increasing space needed with this flat configuration instead of the regex one